# Update master git repository from files

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, branching-and-merging

Hopefully I can explain.

We took over development of a site, and there was a transition period where there was two different teams doing dvelopment for a few weeks, and the only deployment path we had was creating patch files for each feature. In this process the master branch we have in git now is different from what is on the site. There was some code that was never pushed up as patches and now following patches fail because os this.

We are now trying to sync our server with master and will be deploying tags going forward. The issue comes in that there is code in the unversioned site that we need to merge in somehow, and there is a difference in even the files we modified with patch files.

I tried creating a branch, reverting to the beginning of the commits of the project, copied over the code from the server, committing those changes, then merging master into that branch to get a synced up branch. However when I try to merge master it says its up to date. Any ideas on how to get this merged together?

Comment: What way are you reverting to the beginning of the commits? Could you provide commands?

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands:

```
# checkout to the first commit and make branch on it's base
git checkout -b merge_branch <first-commit-sha>

# then copy over and commit files

# and merge
git merge master
```